# How to pass selection from a dropdown to a parent component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, bulma

I currently am setting up a modal component that displays various data of a specific record to the user. The user can then select from a Bulma dropdown component for each of the fields in order to change those fields. Since the dropdown is repeated many times I put it into its own component, but I'm running into a problem because the parent needs to pass the data from the API to the child as a prop, but the child needs to be able to tell the parent when a selection is made so that the parent will be able to update the prop being passed in and also so that the parent's data will be consistent for when the updated data is ready to be sent to the API. I can't think of a way to enable this or if it is even possible. I have tried things like v-model but the majority of examples I've seen don't seem to fit my use case very well.

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown" :class="dropdownClass">
    <label class="dropdown-label">{{ label || "" }}</label>
    <div class="dropdown-trigger" @click="toggleDropdown">
      <button
        class="button ticket-tags is-fullwidth"
        :style="{
          'background-color': backgroundColor,
          color: textColor,
          border: borderStyle
        }"
      >
        <span>{{ firstItem || "" }}</span>
        <span class="icon is-small">
          <i class="bx bx-chevron-down"></i>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div
          class="dropdown-item"
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.data"
          @click="itemSelected"
        >
          {{ item.data }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";

const dropdownComponent = defineComponent({
  name: "Dropdown",
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String
    },
    firstItem: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    items: {
      type: Array
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      type: String
    },
    textColor: {
      type: String
    },
    borderStyle: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  emits: ["itemSelected"],
  setup: (props, context) => {
    const dropdownClass = ref("");
    const toggleDropdown = () => {
      dropdownClass.value =
        dropdownClass.value == "is-active" ? "" : "is-active";
    };
    const itemSelected = (item: any) => {
      dropdownClass.value = "";
      context.emit("itemSelected", item);
    };
    return {
      toggleDropdown,
      dropdownClass,
      itemSelected
    };
  }
});
```

Here is the code for the dropdown. The parent component passes in an array of options (items) as well as which option to display initially for the dropdown (firstItem). So I'm trying to find a way for the child to update the parent component's firstItem. I could be going about this the completely wrong way though. TIA!

Comment: Never really used Vue, but I think this will help https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-trigger-an-onchange-event/11081

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the workaround in your parents vue-file? I will try to give you a solution after that.

But from this point of view, it looks like setup() maybe isn´t the right approach, as you want to execute itemSelected() after the view is rendered.

EDIT:

Maybe you already have a solution, but here is what I would recomend:

```
methods: {
   itemSelected(item) {
     this.$emit("itemSelected", item)
   }
}
```

And at your element:

```
<div
   class="dropdown-item"
   v-for="item in items"
   :key="item.data"
   @click="itemSelected(item)"
   >
      {{ item.data }}
</div>
```

As stated in the documentation [Setup | Vue.js](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#context), when `setup` is executed the component has not been created. So your `emit` have nothing to emit.

Comment: The function actually ended up working and I was able to pass the item through the emit, the only issue I wasn't able to resolve was telling the parent component which field a dropdown was trying to update, which caused me to have to have a separate function for each dropdown to update the corresponding field. I appreciate the help, though!